# WordPress: Remove Elementor from a page but keep formatting

Tags: wordpress, elementor

Is this possible to remove Elementor from a page but keep the formatting done using Elementor?
We can remove Elementor easily but it distorts all UI.

I want to get rid of Elementor but want to keep all the formatting done in past.

Comment: No. Elementor creates it's own markup and if you remove that, you'll lose all styling. If you really need to do this, you could copy the source from the page, and paste it into the WP WYSIWYG editor (the text tab). However, WP may wrap that content too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future reference of other people same issue.
The answer is

**It is not possible**